# Writing a curl proxy under linux

Tags: php, python, curl

Hello
I am working with a legacy system where an ASP.NET application posts an XML file to a server via curl.exe (this url to send is configurable by a .config file).

Now due to legacy system limitations, I need curl post this XML to my ubuntu server by changing the said .congfig file, modify the received XML as I need and finally curl post it to the real server.

How can this be done ? My guess is a php or a python script running under apache2 server, listening posts. Once received the xml file, do the required modifications on the file and post to the real curl server.

Via php or python, how can this be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ASP.NET application is posting XML, you simply need to handle a normal POST request, modify XML to match your requirement and post it using cURL to the real cURL server. In PHP, it would look something like this (more or less meta code, error checking and additional logic is needed):

```
$xml = $_POST['xml'];
// do something with posted XML
.....
// post it to the "real" cURL server
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('xml' => $xml));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

That's about it, check [cURL documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and use what is necessary for POST to work with your server, and your are all good.